# Booting from USB unsuccessful

Tags: boot, live-usb, startup-disk-creator

I currently have Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit installed, and would like to install Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit.

I downloaded the Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit iso file. Then I used Startup Disk Creator to make my new 16 GB Sandisk flash drive bootable with the iso file. That appeared to be successful. I then restarted my computer, and entered the Bios settings so I could make the USB drive the first boot. I saved and exited setup, however my computer gets to the black screen with the white text and stays there not doing anything. I believe it says "Verifying DMI Pool Data..." at the bottom.

I think that making the flash drive bootable was unsuccessful.

Comment: Maybe this question can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably right about the USB not working correctly. The Startup Disk Creator program has a terrible reputation of being really bad at making working USBs.

The method I use to create my live usbs has worked %100 of time for me. It may be a little bit more intimidating if you are not familiar with the Terminal. It really isn't that complicated though.

My method uses the terminal command `dd` to write the iso to the USB. First, you need to have a Terminal open. You need to find the name that Ubuntu has given for the USB so you can tell `dd` to write to it.

`sudo fdisk -l`

The terminal will ask for your password, then it will show a lot of information. You want to find the device that has one or two partitions. It will probably be either sdb or sdc (sda is probably your hard drive).

After you are sure that you found the correct name of the usb you can run the `dd` to write the iso to it. You can change "Downloads" in the command to the directory you saved the ido file in. You must change the "sdx" to the device name you found using the previous command (don't use the numbers).

**Please be careful! Using this command incorrectly can destroy the data on your computer or any device connected to it!**

`sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdx oflag=direct  bs=1048576`

Answer (score 0):

How to change your flashdrive into bootable device?
1.Using command prompt
2.Using Power ISO
3.USB Boot Converter

Note:
Using Power ISO tool..
step1:
change the os into ISO image file.
step2:
open the tools menu in power ISO then select the bootable usb option.
step3:
then copy that image file into the bootable USB.